# How to pass a dynamic number of input values to a controller in Symfony2.1

Tags: symfony, controller, symfony-2.1

Suppose to have a controller in **Symfony2.1** that receives a list of numerical values, e.g.

```
public function showAction($el1, $el2, $el3){...}
```

where I assume that the *i*-th *$eli* is a numerical id. Hence, I will render that controller in a Twig template as follows:

```
{% render 'AcmeBundle:BundleName:show' with {'el1':'1', 'el2':'5',  'el3':'7'}  %}
```

It would be nice to pass a unique value that groups them all (like an array), e.g.

```
public function showAction($els){...}
```

where *$els* is an array of values. Of course I guess it is not possible, even if the controller is rendered inside a Twig template.

The only way I found to let the input a little bit more dynamic is to pass a unique value that groups all the id-input values and to separate them with a token. E.g.:

```
{% render AcmeBundle:BundleName:show with {'els': '1_5_7'} %}
```

Is this the best approach or I can do better?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass an array of arguments?

**Controller:**

```
public function showAction(array $els)
{
    // ...

    return ['els' => $els];
}
```

**View:**

```
{% render 'AcmeBundle:Demo:show' with {'els': {'el1': 1, 'el2': 5, 'el3': 7}} %}
```

or if you want to pass a numeric indexed array:

```
{% render 'AcmeBundle:Demo:show' with {'els': [1, 5, 7]} %}
```

This way you can pass in any number of arguments you want.

Comment: This is true if the array is created manually in the twig template (i.e. with a fixed size and the elements known in advance). How would you do the same by using an array such that it has an unknown length and content? It could be returned by another controller for instance.